# Can public elementary schools present material with a partisan viewpoint?

Tags: united-states, california, education, school, politics

I was listening in on my 3rd grader's online lesson about environment. The pre-recorded video went more or less like this:

1. Environment needs our protection; otherwise you the kids won't have clean air when you grow up.
2. Many countries, including the United States, agreed on protecting environment in Paris Accords.
3. Republicans decided to withdraw from Paris Accords.
4. A multiple choice question: was the withdrawal from Paris Accords good or bad for the environment?

And the video goes on like that about several environment related things, such as Kyoto, etc. And on every item the video makes sure to stress that the blame for destroying the environment falls squarely on the Republicans.

Thus the question: can public schools teach this sort of material that clearly blames one political party for problems?

Comment: A lot of the answer may turn on whether the information being provided -- as opposed to the inferences you think students will draw from it -- is true or false. That fact about the Paris Accords is true; are there other statements that you think would be problematic?

Comment: @bdb484, the problem is that although none of the statements are false, but they are misleading, and they are conditioning the young kids for a particular party allegiance. The same school doesn't teach the kids the Civil War in partisan terms, they don't tell kids that the slaveowners and later KKK members were all Democrats and the abolitionists were all Republicans. IMO public elementary school should not be involved in partisan politics, but this school district does.

Comment: But the civil war was a long time ago and explaining the change in political party stances on various topics would be too much for such young children. Whereas the climate crisis is one supported by science and affects them in the here and now, pointing out the vested interests they're up against is necessary.

Comment: @Michael why do you say it's misleading? Republican's DO have a very negative track record on environmental issues and chances are that these kids will have to deal with the consequences of that more so than any other political decision.

Comment: To answer "Was the withdrawal from the Paris Accords good or bad for the environment?" Requires knowing what would have happened had we not withdrawn. It is impossible to know and therefore the question is unanswerable. It may be answerable if you can make a reasonable justifiable guess, but this is something adults debate. Its not a clear cut answer. The fact that teachers present it as if it is, is the problem.

Comment: @Hilmar, "positive" v "negative" depends on your (and the school district) viewpoint. Republicans believe that strong economy ultimately leads to better environment, and there's a strong evidence of that, for example compare the obscene amount of garbage floating into the ocean from rivers in developing Asian countries and the environmental laws in US and Europe. On the other hand Democrats believe in immediate actions, even ridiculously inefficient like banning plastic straws. It's not "good" v "bad", it's different viewpoints. These complexities the kids couldn't understand yet.

Comment: @Hilmar because Republicans aren't just against the Paris Accords because they're evil.  They have honest reasons for not wanting to be in the PA.  Like not wanting to give up sovereignty to foreign councils, and not wanting to be beholden to rules our biggest rivals won't follow.  The dishonesty in the school's question is that it asserts the PA is good, and then leaves it up to the kids to guess why Republicans want to leave it.

Comment: @michael I think you're making a very salient point. The school is teaching accurate facts, and the student's assessment is whether those facts are positive or negative will depend on his political perspective. If you're a Republican who opposes the Paris Accord, your should be happy to have that fact shared. If you just want to make sure your own child sees the world through the same lens as you, teach him about the environment. If the school is giving them one-sided nonsense, they'll sniff that out; they're a lot smarter than you give them credit for.

Comment: Where in California exactly?  A lot of people like to think Cali is a big far left state but neglect that parts of California are strongly consevative.   California being far left is relatively new (with exception to LBJ in '64, from the 1952 election until the 1992 election, California was a reliable Republican State.  It might help that Nixon and Regan were two of the most historically notable Republican Presidents during this period, but Cali also supported Eisenhower and surprisingly Ford, who lost many other reliable states during his re-election.).

Comment: There is still a very strong, albeit rural population in California that are Republican.

Comment: @bdb484, Silicon Valley.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about law at all. It belongs on politics.se if it belongs anywhere. It may be too opinion based even for politics.

Comment: @DavidSiegel, see a perfectly law-related answer by the user6726 below.

Comment: I've edited the question a bit to remove some of the more heavily opinion-based stuff.  I do think it is a valid question about the law.  Hopefully my edits focus it on the legal question and less on opinions about what constitutes propaganda and brainwashing.

Comment: I would challenge you to find a time when schools did not present  "partisan" viewpoint.  Your issue seems to be that you no longer like the viewpoints presented.

Comment: While I still think it likely to draw opinion-based answers, th4e edit has made me think thius just barely on-topic, and I have withdrawn my close vote. @Michael, please note that an off-topic question can stilt elicit an on-topic answer. Such questions are still closed under this site's policies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless specifically prohibited by law, schools can teach specific viewpoints. An example of "specifically prohibited" is [RCW 42.17A.555](https://apps.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=42.17A.555) in Washington,

> No elective official nor any employee of his or her office nor any
> person appointed to or employed by any public office or agency may use
> or authorize the use of any of the facilities of a public office or
> agency, directly or indirectly, for the purpose of assisting a
> campaign for election of any person to any office or for the promotion
> of or opposition to any ballot proposition. Facilities of a public
> office or agency include, but are not limited to, use of stationery,
> postage, machines, and equipment, use of employees of the office or
> agency during working hours, vehicles, office space, publications of
> the office or agency, and clientele lists of persons served by the
> office or agency.

Your English teacher cannot use the classroom to campaign for a particular candidate or ballot proposition. There is an analogous [law in California](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?sectionNum=8314.&lawCode=GOV), and many (all?) states. A more detailed analysis of the Washington is provided [here](https://www.pdc.wa.gov/learn/guidelines-school-districts), including a long list of basic principles governing allowed vs. prohibited conduct, but it can be reduced to the dichotomy of "particular candidate / proposition" vs. "viewpoint". Viewpoints that are part of the curriculum can and are be mandated by statute or district policy. Employees may have some latitude to express their personal viewpoint, to the extent that they are consistent with the requirements of the curriculum.

For California, one can look for curricular requirements [here](https://www.cde.ca.gov/ci/). A non-technical overview of the 9-12 science curriculum aimed to inform parents is [here](https://www.scoe.net/castandards/Documents/parent_overview_science_9-12.pdf), then you can find more technical details [here](https://www.cde.ca.gov/ci/sc/cf/cascienceframework2016.asp). [This document](https://www.cde.ca.gov/ci/sc/cf/documents/scifwchapter8.pdf) is part of that collection: it's the 4 course high school model (286 pages). You could then compare what is delivered in class to what the Board of Education says is to be delivered.

[Here](https://www.cde.ca.gov/ci/sc/cf/documents/scifwchapter4.pdf) is the Grade 3-5 science curriculum, and [here](https://www.cde.ca.gov/ci/hs/cf/documents/hssfwchapter6.pdf) is grade 3 history and social science. There does not seem to be a requirement to teach a viewpoint nor a prohibition against doing so, but there is actually a requirement that you not be graded based on climate change / greenhouse effect subject matter.

So, probably it is allowed. In context, it could be viewed as campaigning against a political party thus illegal electioneering. I can't find any case law in California that addresses the legality of across-the-board campaigning against a political party using public resources, but [here is a California legal guidance](https://voiceofoc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/ILG-Memo.pdf) on legal and illegal campaign activities.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful and educational.

Comment: links https://www.cde.ca.gov/ci/, https://www.scoe.net/castandards/Documents/parent_overview_science_9-12.pdf, and https://www.cde.ca.gov/ci/sc/cf/cascienceframework2016.asp  fails. I appreciate if you may fix them. I am interested to read those  documents